# Set up Network Bridge for Windows 7 and iPhone X to share internet hotspot with Asus AC2900 RT-AC86U router

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, iphone

I have an iPhone X with hotspot connected to Win7 via USB and the PC is connected to an Asus AC2900 RT-AC86U router via LAN cable. I have tried to go through the [share data with your router](https://www.vpnuniversity.com/tutorial/how-to-share-unlimited-4g-data-with-your-router) setup via PC. If I use the bridge connections between LAN (the router) and LAN 3 (the phone) then

[image]

The network bridge starts up and the phone hotspot shares data with the PC as usual

[image]

With the Bridge Status showing the IPv4 Connectivity as Internet. However, if another PC now connects to the Router there is no internet bridge via the Router. The LAN status shows the IPv4 as Not Connected.

[image]

Funnily enough the Phone connection also shows as Not Connected even though the hotspot works:

[image]

What can I do to get the internet connection to share via this method? THANKS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update. The answer [here] stopped working for the PC. I don't know why. It still works for devices connected to the router. So I got a network bridge going between iPhone13 and my PC WiFi and my Asus Router. As follows:

1. Connect the PC to the router via LAN cable to an ASUS LAN cable port:

[image: LAN port]

Although it doesn't matter. The bridge also works using the blue WAN port.

2. Login to the Asus Router admin and setup the router as default. The default operation mode is wireless router mode.

[image]

3. Turn on iPhone "personal hotspot".
4. Connect to the iPhone by PC Wifi

[image: PC Wifi connection]

5. In PC control panel network connections, select the Wifi connection and the Asus Router and `Bridge Connections`

[image]

6. The bridge connection will be created. If it says it can't be configured, go into the Bridge connection properties and select Wifi and Asus Router.

[image: properties]

7. You now have a network bridge between your iPhone, PC and Asus Router. Devices can connect to the Asus Router and share the iPhone WiFi internet connection.

[image: Bridge connections]

You can also make a bridge between iPhone connected to PC via USB.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use ICS (Internet Connection Sharing) instead of a bridged connection? It works way better, especially with that kind of setup.

Right-click on your Local Area Network 3 icon, choose Properties, go to the Sharing tab, and check the Share this connection box (the other option isn't necessary). You'll be good to go in a matter of seconds, because Windows will know you want to share this iPhone connection with the other available network adapter, namely your Ethernet port.

Comment: thanks, though unfortunately [this happens](https://superuser.com/questions/1535138/set-up-internet-connection-sharing-for-windows-7-and-iphone-x-to-share-internet)

Comment: Oh, have you read this news about the latest iOS update breaking Hotspot on several models of iPhone? See this, among other articles: https://www.any-data-recovery.com/fix-iphone/iphone-personal-hotspot-not-working.html EDIT: it's just to explain that a recent iOS update may have broken Hotspot on your phone altogether, not an invitation to purchase any products. I'll try to find more unbiased material and post if here for you...EDIT #2: https://www.techradar.com/news/ios-134-update-is-landing-on-march-24-and-it-may-fix-an-annoying-iphone-issue

Comment: Per [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/1535138/set-up-internet-connection-sharing-for-windows-7-and-iphone-x-to-share-internet?noredirect=1&lq=1) I had to set up the router as an access point and then the internet connection sharing started working.